# PHP/MySQL time date variable calculations

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 variables, one a date like 06/02/2018 and a day interval that changes. I need to add the two together, then find the difference from the current date.

I've read carbon can help with this but I'm stuck.

say the vending machine was last filled on 6/20/2018 and it needs to be refilled every 30 days. I need to find out how many days from today it needs to be serviced.

Please help

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. Please explain more...

Comment: This API was deprecated a very long time ago, so this is surely of archaeological interest only?

Comment: said fuck it and did it in JS, cause why would anything be easy in PHP :)